# How does Adobe Flash/Flex for iOS compare to MonoTouch?

Tags: ios, apache-flex, xamarin.ios, adobe

With Adobe [now you can make Flash/Flex compile to the iPhone and iPad](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder/features.html).  How does that compare to MonoTouch?

Does the Adobe solution really compile into native iOS code? Or is it just a iOS Air container that runs your code which is able to access the natife iOS calls through the Air container?  I'm wondering what is different with Adobe compared with MonoTouch.

I just want to know the differences between the two technologies.  If any.  Or do they work exactly the same way on principle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They both create a native binary that runs on the device.  The short answer is that monotouch lets you use Apple's SDK in a language other than objective-c.  You also get access to the mono base class library and can write managed code instead of unmanaged.  You are still in essence writing an application much like you would if you chose to use objective-c since monotouch creates bindings to native Cocoa Touch APIs.

Adobe Air/Flex is abstracted a bit more.  Yes it lets you avoid objective-c as well but you aren't really using the Cocoa Touch SDK but Adobe's. This means it is potentially more cross platform but may not perform as well.  It is still ultimately compiled down to a native binary.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the Adobe solution really compile into native iOS code?

Yes, that is why it can take a long time to create a formal release build.  I've reports that it takes anywhere from five minutes (not too bad) to >30 minutes to do an export for iOS.

[Source for this information](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-6c0b8f041331091b3e0-8000.html)

> The Standard method of packaging translates the bytecode of the
>   application's SWF file into ARM instructions before packaging. Because
>   of this additional translation step before packaging, this method of
>   creating an application (IPA) file takes several minutes. The Standard
>   method takes longer than the Fast method. However, the application
>   performance with the Standard method is release-quality, and it is
>   suitable for submission to the Apple App Store.

[Source 2](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac35eb7b4e12cddc5fbbb-8000.html)

> On iOS, ADT converts the SWF file byte code and other source files
>   into a native iOS application.

-

> ```
> Or is it just a iOS Air container that runs your code which is able to access the natife iOS calls through the Air container?
> ```

It is against the Apple Developer Licensing agreements to do any sort of runtime processing or parsing of code.  That is the reason why some features, such as SWFLoader are not support on iOS.

I don't know anything about Monotouch, though, so cannot compare the two.

Comment: good question.   My original question even got voted for "close" I don't know why.

Comment: I'm not sure (since I did not downvote it) but my guess would be ending your answer with *so cannot compare the two* when the question asked is *how does X compare to Y*.

Comment: @7wp I was the one who voted to close. This is the type of question that will solicit debate and extended discussion.  It is not answered with direct facts.  I decided to post my own answer nonetheless to add some factual answers to some of your direct questions.

Answer (score -2):

I think the links below should answer your question

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSADC382C9-CEBC-47c6-81AD-975D9A72C677.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac35eb7b4e12cddc5fbbb-8000.html

Although I don't know anything about monotouch so can't compare.

Comment: I'm unclear how this answer is any different than the one I provided, and I've been downvoted a lot.

Comment: that's true...I am not really sure why the above answer was downvoted

Comment: I'm not sure (since I did not downvote it) but my guess would be ending your answer with *so can't compare* when the question asked is *how does X compare to Y*.